# JavaScript SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, for-loop, syntax-error

I've been getting an "Unexpected end of input" error message when running my program, but however long I keep looking at the code where it occurs. 
I just simply can't figure out where I might be missing something.

```
for (let [key, value] of this.langList) {
  if (key === ('ENG' || 'JAP' || 'CHI' || 'RUS')) {
     this.langListFiltered.set(key, value);
  }
}
```

Comment: That code won't work in any case, but I don't see how it could cause that error.

Comment: That error sounds MS specific. Are you running this in IE? And if so; are you checking for cross-compatibility of your files? This error wasn't caused by this exact code. The snippet you've given is syntactically correct.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is with statment:

```
(key === ('ENG' || 'JAP' || 'CHI' || 'RUS'))
```

You should compare key separately with each string:

```
(key === 'ENG' || key === 'JAP' || key === 'CHI' || key === 'RUS')
```

Comment: `['ENG', 'JAP', 'CHI', 'RUS'].includes(key);` would be a more preferred way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

@N. Djokic gave a solution.

But you can also use an array:

```js
if (['ENG', 'JAP', 'CHI', 'RUS'].includes(key)) {}
```

If you choose this solution, which is more maintable, be carefull to initialize your array earlier in your code, not in your loop.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed above with @Richard. Ideally you initialize the array before the loop. This also helps if the array is bound to change or if you use the array in multiple places.

```
let languageArray = this.langList.keys();
...

if (languageArray.includes(key)) {
   this.langListFiltered.set(key, value);
}
```